# how to map forward/backward buttons to w and s for game play

Tags: windows, mouse, keymap, button-remapping, mouse-buttons

I have many mouse's with those buttons, and mouse clicks give left right up down movements in this specific game, and I have to use the keyboard w s for forward and back, is there a way to map the mouse extra buttons to the W and S ?? thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

This is possible.  Depending on your mouse software, you might be able to remap the buttons in it.  Logitech and other gaming mice often come with software that easily lets you remap buttons.

[AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) can remap mouse clicks as well.

There are third party software programs that do it as well.  You can Google for them.  Here is one [site](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/changing-and-customizing-your-mouse-buttons-actions/) I found.